# CSS Drop caps: using float:left on first letter covers the second letter

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with drop caps and CSS. When I use this code:

```css
.firstcharacter {
  color: #903;
  float: left;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-size: 400%;
  line-height: 80%;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hey.....</h2>
<p>
<span class="firstcharacter">A</span>s a new student of Luke Skywalker's Jedi Academy, follow an ancient tradition and learn the powers - and dangers - of the Force™.</p>
```

The second letter is covered by the drop caps letter. If I take out the float:left part, it doesn't but it no longer looks like drop caps, and if I add a non-breaking space   it works, but the second letter is offset slightly to the right.

With float:
[image: B]

Without float:
[image: A]

Comment: Your code does not exhibit the problem you describe. Can you post an example that shows the problem in action ?

Comment: have you tried removing `float:left` and adding a `margin-right: -x` to your `firstcharacter` class? Or keep the `float:left` if you still want that effect

Comment: @gaby http://vidame.co/tst/ i've taken some of the containers out and made this page, but it's still causing some problem, the second letter is usually beneath the first letter, in this example it is off the side of the page.

Comment: The problem is with the negative margins of the also floated `h1` above it. Adding `clear:left` on the `p` will fix it. (*Notice that the a and s are not overlapped by the big A but they are on the top right where the `h1` left some space..*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thankyou that's perfect!!